# how to use curl --ftp-create-dirs?

Tags: bash, curl, centos, curl-commandline

**Background**

I have been searching the Internet trying to find an example of `--ftp-create-dirs`.

Overall my goal is to use "--ftp-create-dirs" to automatically create the necessary folders if they are not present when I upload my file.

**Problem**

The problem is I don't know the exact syntax for properly using `--ftp-create-dirs`, can someone help me with this?

**My current curl:**

```
curl -k -T 000-0000-0000-000.png -u [username]:[pass] --ftp-create-dirs /test --ftp-ssl  ftp:[ftp server]
```

In the example above, I am trying to upload the .png image and create `/test` on the ftp server if it does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

To add a new directory via FTP:

```
curl ftp://username:password@10.10.10.10/homes/back/newdir/ --ftp-create-dirs
```

Answer (score 3):

Just putting this in here for future reference (and because I keep making the same mistake that I just saw in your code): it is important to end your folder name with a `/` (slash). Otherwise, curl will create a file, not a folder. Here is the command I used:

```
curl -T path/to/local_file.txt ftp://1.2.3.4/my_new_folder/ --ftp-create-dirs -u username:password
```

This will move `local_file.txt` to `my_new_folder` on the FTP server. The folder will be created if it doesn't exist, otherwise, the command will simply be ignored.

If there are any issues with creating the folder, curl will return error number 9 (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html). This can happen if a file with the same name as the new folder already exists in the given directory:

```
curl: (9) Failed to MKD dir: 451
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `/test` after the `--ftp-create-dirs`. Its just a parameter similar to your `-k`(doesn't take any value) at the command.