# cURL create new directory using --ftp-create-dir

Tags: curl, sftp

So I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000102/how-to-use-curl-ftp-create-dirs), but the answer doesn't work for me. I'm connecting to my server using SFTP:

```
curl -k -v sftp://<username>:<password>@12.34.56.78/subdomains/cdn/mynewdir --ftp-create-dirs
```

Output:

```
*Trying 12.34.56.78
*TCP_NODELAY set
*Connected to 12.34.56.78 (12.34.56.78) port 22 (#0)
*SSH MD5 fingerprints: ab12cd34ef56gh78lm98
*SSH authentication methods available: password
*Initialized password authentication
*Authentication complete
*Could not open remote file for reading: no such file or directory
*Connection #0 to host 12.34.56.78 left intact
curl: (78) Could not open remote file for reading: No such file or directory
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the authentication, because I can see my files and other directories, but I just can't seem to create new directories using `--ftp-create-dirs`.

Any bit of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it myself by doing the following:

```
curl -k -v "sftp://<username>:<password>@12.34.56.78/subdomains/cdn/"
     -Q "-MKDIR /subdomains/cdn/mynewdir" --ftp-create-dirs
```

Comment: Did you figure out if there was a way to give relative paths to create based on the curl url? or do they always need to be from root